# Getting error: Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c, runtime-error

Running the following program but getting error as

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'unzip' was corrupted

What can cause the error? Below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fmuUnzip() {
  char fmuFileName[100], path[100],strFinal[100];
  char unzip[]="winzip32 -e -o -j";
  printf("Enter fmuFileName\n");
  gets(fmuFileName);

  printf("Enter path of the fmuFileName\n");
  gets(path);
  strcat(unzip," ");
  strcat(unzip,fmuFileName);
  strcat(unzip," ");
  strcat(unzip,path);
}

void fmuLoad() {
  fmuUnzip();
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
 fmuLoad();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is (are)

```
strcat(unzip," ");   //problem starts here itself
strcat(unzip,fmuFileName);
strcat(unzip," ");
strcat(unzip,path);
```

as, there is not enough memory to hold the concatenated string. Essentially, you're overrunning the allocated memory and it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you define an array with no size specified and initialize that with a string, the effective size of the array gets calculated as the length of the string, plus one more for the null-terminator. Trying to "cat" to that is memory overrrun.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) of `strcat()` (*emphasis mine*)

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. **If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable;** ....

**Solution:**

Define a destination  array bigger enough to hold the concatenated string, including the terminating null, of course.

---

That said, `gets()` is **<del>pure evil</del>** very dangerous , as it suffers from buffer overrun issues. You may want to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: what to do. i want **strcat(unzip," ");** to be there in the program because i want to add space in between unzip string and the path

Comment: @PrajwalBhat I already told that no? _"Define a destination array bigger enough"_, something like `char unzip[512]` or bigger...

Answer (score 0):

In your case `unzip[]="winzip32 -e -o -j";` has space only for your init string, 17 chars + null terminator.
Then your variable has no room to add chars with instructions:

```
strcat(unzip," ");
strcat(unzip,fmuFileName);
strcat(unzip," ");
strcat(unzip,path);
```

You could change to:

```
void fmuUnzip()
{
   char fmuFileName[100], path[100],strFinal[100];
   printf("Enter fmuFileName\n");
   gets(fmuFileName);

   printf("Enter path of the fmuFileName\n");
   gets(path);
   char *unzip = malloc(17+1+strlen(fmuFileName)+strlen(path)+1);
   strcpy(unzip, "winzip32 -e -o -j");
   strcat(unzip," ");
   strcat(unzip,fmuFileName);
   strcat(unzip," ");
   strcat(unzip,path);
}
```

Comment: showing error in  malloc eventhough i have used stdlib.h